# Simple Triangle Completion

Tags: triangles

How do you find the missing point of a triangle, given:

2/3 of the points, two slopes, and one angle of direction. Here's the problem.

There are two points:

Point B (1,1), showing an arrow going up (an undefined slope). 
Point A (3,4), with a 45 degree angle going down and left.

The slope of segment AB is: 1.5

Assuming the missing point will lay on the direction of the 45 degree angle and the undefined slope, where is the missing point and where will they connect.

Answer (score 0):

You can't.  If the $45^\circ$ line from $A$ is referenced to horizontal, its equation is $y=x+1$.  The line from $B$ could intersect it anywhere from $(1+\epsilon,2+\epsilon)$ to $(3-\epsilon,4-\epsilon)$ based on your information